# pass function name directly to event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to attach a function directly to a `change` event in jQuery, but I can't quite figure it out. I need to pass the element that has changed as a paramater to the function I'm invoking.

Something like this, ( but it doesn't work ):

```
var fun = function( trigger ){
  // do something
};

$( 'select' ).change( fun( $(this) ) );
```

The following works:

```
$( 'select' ).change( function(){
  fun( $(this) );
});
```

I've also tried (just for the hell of it)

```
$( 'select' ).bind( 'change', fun( $(this) ) );
```

But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('select').change(fun);
```

Will do the trick. You will be able to access `this` inside the `fun` function.

Here is an example:

```
var fun = function(){
    console.log(this);//output will be the DOM element that had the `change` event fire
};

$( 'select' ).change( fun );
```

Your second solution works because the anonymous function you are passing as the event handler is given access to the `this` variable and you are then passing it to the `fun` function. Any function passed to a jQuery event handler will recieve the `this` variable that stores a reference to the DOM element that had the event fire on it.